# Printer PIXMA MP250 no longer prints after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: drivers, printing, 14.04, canon, pixma

When looking at localhost:631, I'm seeing:

```
stopped  "The PPD version (5.2.9) is not compatible with Gutenprint 5.2.10-pre2."
```

The original drivers are quite old (2010), and I needed to install libtiff4 by hand to install the .deb packages. Does anyone know how to get it to work? Are there any alternative drivers?